# Inconsistent behaviour with IntersectionObserver API

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I have the requirement to display multiple animated counters on a web page where the animation is triggered when the element is intersecting based on the **IntersectionObserver API** return.

**What I have observed is that despite the API returning true for all the counters most of the time only the first animation is executed and for the rest of the animations I need to scroll the page up/down for the rest of the counters to animate.**

This inconsistent behaviour holds true even if I just need to replace the inner text with the value from data-attribute (did this to validate that animation script is not the culprit).

Below is the code and the screenshot of the 3 counters on a single web page, off the three only the first one works even if all the three counters are within the first fold of the screen.

HTML:

```
<div class="counter-value" data-count="10000">0</div>
<div class="counter-value" data-count="183.4">0</div>
<div class="counter-value" data-count="270">0</div>
```

JS:

```
var config = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0.5
};

function callback(entry, observer){
    console.log(entry);
    if (entry[0].isIntersecting) {

        var $this = $(entry[0].target),
            countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

        $this.prop({
            countNum: $this.text()
        }).animate({
            countNum: countTo
        },
        {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function () {
                $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
            },
            complete: function () {
                var localNum = this.countNum.toLocaleString()
                $this.text(localNum);
                console.log(localNum);
            }
        });
        observer.unobserve(entry[0].target);
    };
};

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback,config);
var counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter-value'); //make this an array if more than one item
counters.forEach(counter => {
    observer.observe(counter);
});
```

[image: Screenshot of counters and console]

Any pointers on this if you have ever faces such an issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intersection Observer API accepts a callback that sets the first argument to **all** the entries attached to the observer. You have to loop through all of them and check whether they intersect.

```
function callback(entries, observer){
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {

        var $this = $(entry.target),
            countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

        $this.prop({
            countNum: $this.text()
        }).animate({
            countNum: countTo
        },
        {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function () {
                $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
            },
            complete: function () {
                var localNum = this.countNum.toLocaleString()
                $this.text(localNum);
                console.log(localNum);
            }
        });
        observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  }
};
```